# Automate menu actions within a GUI app?

Tags: gui, automation, arduino

I'm currently programming an ESP8266 chip through the Arduino IDE. However, I have two versions of the IDE running at once, because I need an older version to upload files to the chip, and the newer version for other features. Whenever I want to test my program, I have to wait for it to compile in the newer IDE, then switch over to the older version to upload all the LittleFS files.

So I'm wondering: Is there a way to automate this process? To upload the files, I have to switch windows and select a menu option. It's a GUI, and there isn't a way to access it from the command line.

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Comment: What about `esptool` from commandline?

Comment: I have not experience, but https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/xdotool.1.html may be what you are looking for.